# Why is the edge of my disparity map so fat?

Tags: opencv, edge-detection, disparity-mapping

I use the BM algorithm in openCV for binocular matching. The original images are speckle patterns.The disparity image`s edge is fat. I want to know how to correct the edge?

I know the fat edge is the result of cost-aggregation using boxfilter.

But the disparity of other method of cost-aggregation is so bad.

In addition,I used the disparity post-filter and matching-cost distribution to solve this problem,but it does not work.

The first image is the left speckle pattern, and the second image is the disparity image using BM in opencv.

[image: left speckle pattern]

[image: OpenCV BM]

There is my code calling the BM algorithm of opencv :

```
bm->setPreFilterType(StereoBM_C::PREFILTER_NORMALIZED_RESPONSE); 
bm->setBlockSize(9); 
bm->setMinDisparity(0); 
bm->setNumDisparities(64); 
bm->setPreFilterSize(5); 
bm->setPreFilterCap(31); 
bm->setTextureThreshold(10); 
bm->setUniquenessRatio(10); 
copyMakeBorder(leftImg, leftImg, 0, 0, 64, 0, cv::BORDER_REPLICATE); 
copyMakeBorder(rightImg, rightImg, 0, 0, 64, 0, cv::BORDER_REPLICATE); 
bm->compute(leftImg, rightImg, disp); 
disp = disp.colRange(64, leftImg.cols);
```

Comment: Can you add your code that you used to generate the depth image from the `StereoBM()` call?

Comment: There is my code calling the BM algorithm of opencv

Comment: bm->setPreFilterType(StereoBM_C::PREFILTER_NORMALIZED_RESPONSE); 
bm->setBlockSize(9);
bm->setMinDisparity(0);
bm->setNumDisparities(64);
bm->setPreFilterSize(5);
bm->setPreFilterCap(31);
bm->setTextureThreshold(10);
bm->setUniquenessRatio(10); 

copyMakeBorder(leftImg, leftImg, 0, 0, ndisparities, 0, cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
copyMakeBorder(rightImg, rightImg, 0, 0, ndisparities, 0, cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
bm->compute(leftImg, rightImg, disp);
disp = disp.colRange(ndisparities, leftImg.cols);

Comment: Please add your code to the post itself with an edit, not in a comment :)